# How can I access session object in CKAN extension?

Tags: python, session, plugins, ckan

I am writing an CKAN extension, where I am implementing CKAN interface IAuthenticator and I need to save some additional information about logged-in user in session. I have found out that CKAN uses beaker session. How can I access it? [In the documentation of CKAN](http://ckan.readthedocs.org/en/255-update-api-docs/writing-extensions.html#libraries-available-to-extensions) is just one sentence: *The Session object is available through the toolkit.*

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

The session is available as a variable to templates, but it doesn't contain much information - just some info about the User's session cookie. The cookie itself just contains an auth token.

http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/theming/variables-and-functions.html#session

What are you trying to do - what info about the user do you need and where are you trying to access it?

Comment: Hi, I need to save current roles of user to session (I cannot persist them in DB) and then I need to access it in authorization functions for actions like package_create, package_update.

Comment: You could store whatever you want in the session cookie, but that is not a very good way to store data you need for business logic. Why can you not save the roles to the db?

Comment: And how can I access session cookie? I am using now pylons.session. I just cannot because that roles may differ each time and via user's API key would be possible to have given role till the next login of user. It's complicated...